# What is work of task.c file in free rtos

Tags: freertos

I was reading about free rtos. As I understand whole free rtos program are the combination of header files and source files.

the following are the most important source files in free rtos:

1. FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c
2. FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c
3. FreeRTOS/Source/list.c

I know the meaning of queue.c and list.c. I know single or multiple task's run on single processor. I don't understand What is work of task.c file in free rtos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not exactly, FreeRTOS has another one necessary file: port.c (or port.asm). This platform dependent file and it link hardware with software part. This file using functions from tasks.c to provide scheduling mechanism.
For more details please see the official documentation: https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-porting-guide.html

Answer (score 1):

The task.c file contains all the routines for creating and managing FreeRTOS tasks. Some examples are xTaskCreate(), vTaskDelay() etc. See the API reference for the full list [FreeRTOS API Reference](https://www.freertos.org/a00106.html)